# 'flutterfire@*' is not in this registry

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am working on integrating firebase into a flutter project. And I am struggling with no reason with running the command : `flutterfire configure`

I have installed the Firebase cli and logged into my account and set up the project on the firebase console. but for some reason, the firebase_options.dart is not being created.

here's a complete log about the issue:

```
PS D:\flutter apps\flutter_firebase_1> npx flutterfire configure
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/flutterfire - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'flutterfire@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Comment: Explanation below, but this seems like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You might want to explain why you're trying to use `npx` rather than running the program as documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=web#install-cli-tools.

Answer (score 0):

The FlutterFire CLI is a Dart program, **not** an NPM module, so it can't be run with NPX.